# Taiga-back connection reused

Tags: connection-refused, taiga

I had a fresh install of taiga-back (and taiga-front also, but I guess, it's doesn't matter). 
I was following every step on the offical documentiaton (production mode). But!
When I tried run the "test" backend (with the python manage.py runserver command) to see everything is working right (192.168.1.241:8000/api/v1, it's running on a ubuntu server, I'm working in a shell connection). I can't reach the site. I got connection refused.

My local.py

```
from .common import *

MEDIA_URL = "http://localhost/media/"
STATIC_URL = "http://localhost/static/"
SITES["front"]["scheme"] = "http"
SITES["front"]["domain"] = "localhost"

SECRET_KEY = "secret"

DEBUG = False
PUBLIC_REGISTER_ENABLED = False

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "dev@example.com"
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

#CELERY_ENABLED = True

EVENTS_PUSH_BACKEND = "taiga.events.backends.rabbitmq.EventsPushBackend"
EVENTS_PUSH_BACKEND_OPTIONS = {"url": "amqp://taiga:PASSWORD_FOR_EVENTS@localhost:5672/taiga"}
```

Thanks everyone for helping!